# Get all output from sqlite3 in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I have a table with 2 entry :

```
id hostname     ip           port
1  Raspberry pi 192.168.1.49 22
2  Test         127.0.0.1    22
```

In my code i get only the first entry with sqlite3.

I have :

```
{"id": "1", "hostname": "Raspberry pi", "ip": "192.168.1.49", "port": "22"}
```

Where is the second entry ?

I tried with printf and get the same problem it's not json issue.

There is the code :

```
#include <stdarg.h> /* va_list */
#include <stddef.h> /* NULL */
#include <stdint.h> /* int64_t */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* memset */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <kcgi.h>
#include <kcgihtml.h>
#include <kcgijson.h>
static int callback(void *ptr, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    struct kjsonreq *req = (struct kjsonreq *)ptr;
    struct khtmlreq  r;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
    kjson_putstringp(req, azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
  }
}

int
main(void)
{
  struct kreq r;
  struct kjsonreq req;
  const char *page = "index";

  if (khttp_parse(&r, NULL, 0, &page, 1, 0) != KCGI_OK)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  khttp_head(&r, kresps[KRESP_STATUS],
    "%s", khttps[KHTTP_200]);
  khttp_head(&r, kresps[KRESP_CONTENT_TYPE],
    "%s", kmimetypes[r.mime]);
  khttp_body(&r);
  kjson_open(&req, &r);
  kjson_obj_open(&req);
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
        int rc;
        rc = sqlite3_open("/var/www/MaSSH/databases/massh.db", &db);
        if(rc){
                sqlite3_close(db);
        }
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM hosts;", callback, &req, &zErrMsg);
        if(rc!= SQLITE_OK){
                sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
  kjson_obj_close(&req);
  kjson_close(&req);
  khttp_free(&r);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: When you run the code in a debugger, does it enter the `callback` function twice?

Comment: I added printf("ONE TIME"); in callback and its print only 1 time.

Comment: I never used debugger i have gdb but tried to run it runned well dont know how to know if it enter the callback twice.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you use the correct database? How do you get the two rows you show first?

Comment: Why in the world are you using that `sqlite3_exec()` callback interface instead of a [prepared statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) like normal? It's only any good for printing out values, not for anything that needs to use the results.

Comment: Also if your compiler isn't warning you about a major issue with your callback function, you **really** need to enable warnings. (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc or clang)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sys/types.h> /* size_t, ssize_t */
#include <stdarg.h> /* va_list */
#include <stddef.h> /* NULL */
#include <stdint.h> /* int64_t */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* memset */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <kcgi.h>
#include <kcgihtml.h>
#include <kcgijson.h>
int
main(void)
{
  struct kreq r;
  struct kjsonreq req;
  const char *page = "index";

  if (khttp_parse(&r, NULL, 0, &page, 1, 0) != KCGI_OK)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  khttp_head(&r, kresps[KRESP_STATUS],
    "%s", khttps[KHTTP_200]);
  khttp_head(&r, kresps[KRESP_CONTENT_TYPE],
    "%s", kmimetypes[r.mime]);
  khttp_body(&r);
  kjson_open(&req, &r);
  kjson_obj_open(&req);
  sqlite3 *db;
  sqlite3_stmt *res;
  int rc;
  rc = sqlite3_open("/var/www/MaSSH/databases/massh.db", &db);
  if(rc){
    sqlite3_close(db);
  }
  rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM hosts;", -1, &res, 0);
  while((rc = sqlite3_step(res)) == SQLITE_ROW){
    kjson_objp_open(&req, "host");
    kjson_putstringp(&req, "id", sqlite3_column_text(res,0));
    kjson_putstringp(&req, "hostname", sqlite3_column_text(res,1));
    kjson_putstringp(&req, "ip", sqlite3_column_text(res,2));
    kjson_putstringp(&req, "port", sqlite3_column_text(res,3));
    kjson_obj_close(&req);
  }
  sqlite3_close(db);
  kjson_obj_close(&req);
  kjson_close(&req);
  khttp_free(&r);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers aren't useful - you should explain your answer and possibly focus it down to just the important lines of code